# I can't create a dynamic array in a function and return it?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-arrays

Im trying to get certain elements *(in this case which are over some price)* added to another array and then return this new array at the end of the function **(sortPrice)** .

After that I want to assign this new array to a freshly created one in **main()** : "product *sortedPrice"

But I get this error:

"primerenIzpit1.c: In function 'main':
primerenIzpit1.c:104:17: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'product * {aka struct Product *}' from type 'product {aka struct Product}'
sortedPrice = sortPrice(products, 50);"

I understand its something with the types of the func and the array but I really need help.

Just to be clear. I have a question about this certain error all the other code is there just for information. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Product
{
    char name[30];
    int code;
    char date[11];
    float price;
} product;

void addProduct(product *products, FILE *fp)
{
    products = (product *)realloc(products, (3 + 1) * sizeof(product));
    scanf("%s", products[3].name);
    scanf("%d", &products[3].code);
    scanf("%s", products[3].date);
    scanf("%f", &products[3].price);

    fp = fopen("in.bin", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fwrite(&products[3], sizeof(product), 1, fp) != 1)
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

product sortPrice(product *products, float setPrice)
{
    product *newProducts;
    int newSize = 1;
    newProducts = (product *)calloc(newSize, sizeof(product));

    int pos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (setPrice < products[i].price)
        {
            strcpy(newProducts[pos].name, products[i].name);
            newProducts[pos].code = products[i].code;
            strcpy(newProducts[pos].date, products[i].date);
            newProducts[pos].price = products[i].price;

            newSize++;
            newProducts = (product *)realloc(newProducts, newSize * sizeof(product));
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return newProducts;
}

void saveToTxt(FILE *fp)
{
    char savedName[30];
    int savedCode;
    char savedDate[11];
    float savedPrice;

    product savedProduct;
    fp = fopen("in.bin", "rb");
    fread(&savedProduct, sizeof(product), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("Binary Item:\n    Name: %s\n    ID: %d\n    Expire Date: %s\n    Price: %f\n", savedProduct.name, savedProduct.code, savedProduct.date, savedProduct.price);

    // TXT FILE
    fp = fopen("outTxt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %d %s %f", savedProduct.name, savedProduct.code, savedProduct.date, savedProduct.price);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("outTxt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %s %f", savedName, &savedCode, savedDate, &savedPrice);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("Text Item:\n    Name: %s\n    ID: %d\n    Expire Date: %s\n    Price: %f\n", savedName, savedCode, savedDate, savedPrice);
}

int main()
{
    // Dynamic Array
    product *products, *sortedPrice;
    products = (product *)calloc(3, sizeof(product));

    // File
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("in.bin", "wb");
    fclose(f);

    // TXT FILE
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("outTxt", "w");
    fclose(fp);

    addProduct(products, f);

    sortedPrice = sortPrice(products, 50);
    printf("%s - %d - %s - %f\n", sortedPrice->name, sortedPrice->code, sortedPrice->date, sortedPrice->price);

    saveToTxt(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the function signature for `sortPrice` says it returns a `product`, but the function actually returns a `product*`. Try changing that to `product* sortPrice(product *products, float setPrice) { ... }`

Comment: @yano Yes I tried that before but i get this result when printing at the end: " - 0 -  - 0.000000" which means i may have a problem in the function itself but i can't find it.

Comment: in the `for` loop, you unconditionally increment `pos`, but conditionally `realloc(newProducts, ...)`. For the right conditions, `pos` will jump too far ahead and access `newProducts` out of bounds. I think you only want to `pos++` when you `realloc`. Step thru with a debugger and see if that's happening.